# Tapestry File Upload via Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat7, tapestry

I have problems with file uploading on Tapestry 5.3.6. 
I am using this as a reference http://tapestry.apache.org/uploading-files.html
With Jetty web server, everything is fine, file gets uploaded into project directory.
But, If I run app on Tomcat, file get uploaded into Tomcat directory.
Is there any way to point Tomcat to upload file to project directory?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know, you can contribute with a parameter in the contributeApplicationDefaults method in AppModule, like

> configuration.add(UploadSymbols.REPOSITORY_LOCATION,);

Try that.